# Weird mesh mistake that can't be edited in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, edit-mode, object-mode

[image: How mesh looks in object mode]

[image: How mesh looks in edit mode]

Hiya new to this site so forgive me for getting things wrong! The photos should clearly show what is wrong but further information is that this happened after i did a running animation, i went back into object mode and the body mesh had been moved back along the y axis, when i moved it forward in edit mode it was fine, go back into object mode and it is like the picture.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Check your weighting.

Comment: If you have modifiers, [select show in edit mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) to see influence of modifier in edit mode.